# How do I pass two (or more) API props to a NextJs Page?

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api, react-props

I'm trying to render a page with two props from different API fetches.

The adress bar looks like this: http://localhost:3000/startpage?id=1

And the code looks like this, with the first API fetch:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { id } = context.query;

  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BACKEND_URL}/User/${id}`);
  const data = await res.json();
  // console.log(data);

  return {
    props: { user: data },
  };
};
```

Second API fetch looks like this

```
export const getServerSideProps2 = async (context) => {
  const { id } = context.query;

  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BACKEND_URL}/User/${id}/favorites`);
  const data = await res.json();
  //console.log(data);

  return {
    props: { favorites: data },
  };
};
```

And the page that I am trying to render then looks like this:

```
function StartPage( {user, favorites} ){
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.formGroup}>
        <h1>Welcome {user.name}</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>These are your favorite movies:</h1>
        {favorites.map(favorite => (
          <div key={favorite.id}>
            <h5>favorite.name</h5>
          </div>
          
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm guessing that there's a way to put both API fetches in the same function. But I don't know how to. If anyone has any suggetions on how to do that I'd be happy to listen.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? You can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to await multiple promises at the same time.

Comment: Will try that! Thank you! What I want to do is display the user’s name from the /user/${id} api and that users list of favorite movies from /User/${id}/favorites

Answer (score 1):

You can make the calls in the same method and pass both data:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { id } = context.query;

  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BACKEND_URL}/User/${id}`);
  const data = await res.json();

  const resFav = await fetch(`${process.env.BACKEND_URL}/User/${id}/favorites`);
  const dataFav = await resFav.json();

  return {
    props: { user: data, favorites: dataFav },
  };
};
```

No need to declare `getServerSideProps2`